# Data contiguity in an array in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to see if any series of data, beginning at array position 0, is contiguous in the sense that array[0] has a numerical value of 0, array[1] has a numerical value of 1, and so on. For example:

```
    private void isContiguous(int[] array, int position){
        for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i ++){
            if(!array[i].equals(null)){
                long previous = this.extract_long(array[i - 1], OFFSET);
                long current = this.extract_long(array[i], OFFSET);
                    if((previousOffset/PACKET_LENGTH) < ){

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

is about as far as I can think of for a general solution. This is kinda bending my mind so it'd be nice to have some help :)

Comment: If you are checking something for null you sould use `something != null`. So please change you if line to `if(array[i] != null)`.

Comment: What are OFFSET, extract_ling and PACKET_LINK? Anyway, why do you need longs if you are checking int values...?

Comment: Even reading your code, I don't understand your problem. Where does extract_long and PACKET_LENGTH come into it?  BTW an `int` does have an equals() method and is never `null`

Comment: @helios, `array` is an `int[]` so you can't compare with `null`

Comment: @Sam P, If you know the only valid combination for this array is to have a give spacing, why have the array at all, you should be able to calculate each value using a simple function and there would be no array to validate.

Comment: I need the array as I'm storing "packets" of data that can arrive out of sequence. I used int as a placeholder so that the answer I would get would be more general, but I've ended up confusing some people! Sorry :)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: D'oh! You're right :) Excuse me!!! NO NULLS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to start with:

```
public static boolean isContiguous(int[] array) {
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
     if (array[i+1]-array[i] != 1) {
        return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

(I don't know why you need position, OFFSET, and so on, but the above code should fulfill the written requirement)

Comment: That's the best solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @Sam P, If this is the solution, you don't need the array at all, instead of `array[n]` you can just write `first_value + n`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you if you are storing primitive int in your array, they can never have a null value! The array itself might be null, but the values cannot!
Secondly if all you want to check is if array[0]==0, array[1]==1, array[2]==2 then your code should be as simple as this:

```
private boolean isContiguous(int []array) {
 if( array == null ) return false;//a null array cannot be contiguous as it doesn't contain any elements!
 for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
  if( array[i] != i ) return false;
 return true;
}
```

Would this not work?

Comment: yeah, Guys, I kinda forgot to modify it to make more sense in a general setting. Ignore the type faulting and focus on the question, if possible.

That's an interesting way to do it, but it's not a general solution. The placeholder "int" can be any number. I might re-ask this question, because I think I may have confused more people with crap code lol

Comment: I would say a null array is contiguous, because an empty array is contiguous too. ([Vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)). To avoid a discussion/confusion, it might be better to throw a NullPointerException?